# Powershell script not working right with "pause" in the end

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a strange problem with my script, which runs on two different servers, on one server it's working perfectly and on the other one it's behave very strange.

Here is the code:

```
write-host "Cheking if App open please wait"

write-host "`n"

$open = Get-SmbOpenFile | 
          Where-Object {$_.Path -eq "d:\Shares\Share1\app.exe"} |
            Select-Object @{l="Who is using App?";e="ClientUserName"}, Path

if ($open) {
 write-host "Showing open files:"
  $open

}

else {
  write-host "all closed"
}

pause
```

On a server 2012 r2 with powershell version 3.0 it's working perfectly,
and on the second server which is 2016 it's not working.

So I've started to investigate and I came to a conclusion that if I remove the "pause"
in the end of the script on the 2016 server it's working perfectly, which is very strange..

With the "pause" in the end, I'am getting this result:

```
Showing open files:

Press Enter to continue...:
```

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: @Olaf I want to run the script and that in the end it won't close the window of the script

Comment: @Olaf I've found out that i can add ```powershell -version 5.1 -noexit``` but i don't understand when do i add it? in the begging or in the end of the script?

Comment: @Olaf, Thank you for your help, I did that, and it didn't work, it's showing the same output

Comment: it's not showing any open files (and there are), it's shows only "Showing open files:

Press Enter to continue...: "

Comment: Now I understood what you mean. I thought you're complaining about the command `Pause`.  ;-)  ...  You reference a local path in your code `d:\Shares\Share1\app.exe`. That local path likely does not exist on the other server.

Comment: @Olaf it's not correct, if i run the script without the line that you advised or without the pause argument in the end, it's work

Comment: So you're saying that the script is working fine when you delete the command `Pause`???  ... so what is your problem??????

Comment: @Olaf the problem is that i can't run it in the console only in the ISE, and on a older server version it's running in the console

Comment: What means "can't run it in the console"??

Comment: @olaf that means that it's run correctly only in the ISE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format-table (implied) waits indefinitely for 2 objects.

Hmm, format-table never comes out before the pause.

```
[pscustomobject]@{name='joe'}; pause

Press Enter to continue...:
name
----
joe
```

With format-list, it comes out right away:

```
[pscustomobject]@{name='joe'}|format-list; pause

name : joe


Press Enter to continue...:
```

This should work:

```
write-host "Cheking if App open please wait"

write-host "`n"

$open = Get-SmbOpenFile | 
          Where-Object {$_.Path -eq "d:\Shares\Share1\app.exe"} |
            Select-Object @{l="Who is using App?";e="ClientUserName"}, Path

if ($open) {
 write-host "Showing open files:"
  $open | format-list

}

else {
  write-host "all closed"
}

pause
```

Comment: It runs automatically for objects with under 5 properties.

Comment: sorry i don't understand

Comment: You are my hero ! this is actually worked ! - only when I've added ```$open | format-list``` it worked !